# vulkan how to determine if a VkCommandBuffer is safe to destroy?

Tags: vulkan

So after I `vkQueueSubmit` a `VkCommandBuffer`, How can I know it's safe to free or reset that buffer if I don't wan't to `vkQueueWaitIdle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a `VkFence` to `vkQueueSubmit` when you submit the command buffer. When that fence signals (`vkWaitForFences` or `vkGetFenceStatus`), it's safe to free or reset the command buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This is why queue submission operations usually have a `VkFence` in them. That tells you when the submission operation has completed. When the fence is signaled, you can do whatever you like with the command buffer.

Of course, to avoid needless waiting on buffer execution, you should use multiple command buffers. That is, while one is being used, you can be writing to another for the next frame.